# Neo4j/Cypher - LIMIT makes query run faster although less results are returned

Tags: neo4j, cypher, limit

I have created a graph which holds information about movies and people who have worked at those movies either as crew or cast. The following query is supposed to find directors who have at least one pair of movies with X amount of years between their release dates.

```
MATCH (p:Person)-[r1:CREW]->(m1:Movie), (p:Person)-[r2:CREW]->(m2:Movie)
WHERE r1.job = 'Director' AND r2.job = 'Director' AND m1.movie_id < m2.movie_id
AND ABS(duration.between(m1.release_date, m2.release_date).years) >= 50
RETURN DISTINCT p.id, p.name
LIMIT 1000000
```

This LIMIT at the end makes the query actually run and pretty fast too. Without that limit, the execution takes a long time and then throws a heap exception. Please note, as stated in the title, that the results returned are about 40-50. It makes no sense to me that this runs faster with the LIMIT since it does not actually LIMIT anything...or does it? Any help appreciated.

EDIT: 
I am using neo4j version 4.0.4 Community Edition
My graph contains about 400000 nodes and 1.2 million relationships.

As requested in the comments:
Here is a profile execution with the LIMIT
[image]

And here is an explain plan without the LIMIT:
[image]

Comment: how big is your graph? can you also share a PROFILE execution with the LIMIT and an EXPLAIN plan without the limit?

Comment: also please share the neo4j version and edition you used

Comment: @MichaelHunger Hello. I have edited my question with what you asked.

Comment: The team also asked for these statistics `curl -H accept:application/json -H content-type:application/json -d '{"statements":[{"statement":"CALL db.stats.retrieve(\"GRAPH COUNTS\")"}]}' http://_________:7474/db/data/transaction/commit > graphCounts.json`

Answer (score 0):

Yes that's a planner issue, I think it should also go away when you leave off the `:Movie` label on the 2nd node.

It shouldn't do two outside scans and then a join in the middle. Unfortunately there is no planner hint that tells it not to.

In your case the expand from left to right makes more sense as it narrows down as it goes along.

btw. you can also elevate the job to the rel-type so have `:DIRECTED` instead of job=director which makes it also more efficient.

Comment: Hello. Thanks for the answer. I cannot create a rel-type DIRECTED because someone in the CREW of a movie could have many different jobs, not just a few. Unless there is a way to dynamically create the relationship types when batch importing the data.